# JAXB2Marshaller not unmarshaling xml element into Character

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am having problem unmarshalling xml element into character using JAXB2Marshaller.

My XML input contains one element `<dateCheckFlag>Y</dateCheckFlag>`: 
when  I try to get `dateCheckFlag` element value into `Character` type in my pojo, it gives me null.

Assume all setter getter and constructor are present.

Can anybody help me out how to unmarshall xml element into Character...?

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Emp")
class Emp
{
    @XmlElement(name="name");
        String name;
    @XmlElement(name="dateCheckFlag");
        Character dateCheckFlag;
Emp(){}

Emp(String name, Character dateCheckFlag)
{ 
 this.name= name;
 this.dateCheckFlag = dateCheckFlag;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
 this.name=name;
}
public String getName()
{
 return name;
}

public void setDateCheckFlag(Character flag)
{
 this.dateCheckFlag=flag;
}
public Character getName()
{
 return dateCheckFlag;
}
```

Comment: You need to share your code.

Comment: I added small code snapshot when i try to call getDateCheckFlag() method it return me null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) specification does not define the XML representation for `char`/`Character`. 
By default that JAXB reference implmentation converts a `Character` to the `xs:unsignedShort` type.  This means that it is expecting a document like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Emp>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <dateCheckFlag>89</dateCheckFlag>
</Emp>
```

**XmlAdapter**

You will be able to use an `XmlAdapter` to get the XML that you are looking for.  An `XmlAdapter` allows you to convert one object to another for the purposes of changing the XML representation.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class CharacterAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Character> {

    @Override
    public Character unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
        return string.charAt(0);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Character character) throws Exception {
        return new String(new char[] {character});
    }

}
```

**Emp**

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation is used to specify the `XmlAdapter`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Emp")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Emp {

    String name;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CharacterAdapter.class)
    Character dateCheckFlag;

}
```

**Demo**

Below is some code that converts the XML to/from the object model.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Emp.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum15240702/input.xml");
        Emp emp = (Emp) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(emp, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Emp>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <dateCheckFlag>Y</dateCheckFlag>
</Emp>
```

Comment: I was giving Y instead of 89... I used XmlAdaptor for Date Conversion into .java.sql.Date...

Comment: thanks a lot for such nice explanation.  this is what i exactly did for converting java date into sql date.